# Dart using instances within class

Tags: dart

I am trying to implement some dataframe functionality, just as an example to teach myself Dart and OPP.

I am using VSCode with the Dart extension. In the below code I was expecting `df.columns.` in the print statement to bring up autocomplete for `col1`, `col2`, `col3`, but it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

```dart
class Columns {
  List<int> col1;
  List<int> col2;
  List<String> col3;

  Columns(this.col1, this.col2, this.col3);
}

class DataFrame {
  var columns;
  DataFrame(col1, col2, col3) {
    columns = Columns(col1, col2, col3);
  }
}

var df = DataFrame(
  [1, 2, 3],
  [5, 6, 7],
  ['red', 'blue', 'red'],
);
void main() {
  print(df.columns.); // no autocomplete for col1, col2, col3
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it was because df was a DataFrame, which has an un-typed member named columns.  If you change that to `Columns columns`, it should work juxt fine.

Also, in general, member names that end in numeric sequences are generally a code smell.  Unrelated to your problem though.

Comment: please mark this as the answer if it informed you.